# going through a list retrieving other list

Tags: scheme

```
(define *graph* (read (open-input-file "test.sxml")))

(define get
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((null? l) '())
          ((equal? 'opm:artifacts (car l))  l)
          (else (get (cdr l))))))

(get *graph*)
```

I have this recursive function that goes through the list and returns the rest of a list that starts with "opm:artifacts".

It works on other lists. 
For example, it works for the list `(1 2 3 4)`; when I call the function, 
`(get 2)` returns `(2 3 4)`.

`test.sxml` is a list.  I checked it with `list?`.

Comment: Please check your facts.  Your presentation is inconsistent.  `(get 2)` certainly will not work with the definition you show.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (get l)
  (match l
    [(? null?) '()]
    [(list 'opm:artifacts _ ...) l]
    [(list _ rs ...) (get rs)]))
```

Comment: Where are you getting `match`?

Comment: That doesn't actually look any different, except you are defining it with pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (get mat ls*)
  (define (get* ls)
    (cond ((null? ls) '())
          ((and (list? (car ls)) (not (null? (car ls))))  
           (if (equal? mat (caar ls)) 
               (car ls)
               (let ((sub-result (get* (car ls))))
                 (if (null? sub-result)
                     (get* (cdr ls))
                     sub-result))))

          (else (get* (cdr ls)))))
  (let ((result (get* ls*)))
    (if (null? result)
        '()
        (cdr result))))

(get 'b '(a (b c d) e)) ;-> '(c d)
(get 'b '((a (b c d) e))) ;-> '(c d)
(get '() '( 4 6 () (2 ()) (() () ()))) ;-> '(() ())
```

I've also generalized it so you can hand in what you want it to match against.